# How to know which sprite has collided with a bullet in its group?

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

Im making a game where a player shoots bullets at incoming boulders, which destroys them. It all functions well and good, but it seems a bit plain when the boulder's destroyed. I want to display an explosion image where the boulder was destroyed. To do this, I need to know which exact boulder has been destroyed in my boulder group.

Relevant code

```
pygame.sprite.groupcollide(boulder_grp, bullet_grp, True, True)
```

The `boulder_grp` contains the boulders that spawns, and the `bullet_grp` contains the bullet that the player shoots. I want to know which boulder in the grp was destroyed, so I can `blit` an image at that exact spot. How do I go about doing this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pygame.sprite.groupcollide`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.groupcollide) returns a dictionary with the sprites.

```py
collide_dict = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(boulder_grp, bullet_grp, True, True)
for boulder in collide_dict:
    print(boulder.rect)
```